# Examples of websites that use Ur/Web

Tags: web, web-applications

I'm going to do a presentation and it would be awesome if anyone could provide me with web apps that use Ur/Web. I already know of https://www.bazqux.com/ but I need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It is too late, but leaving the answer here anyway)

The latest, but incomplete, list of applications could be found at at:
http://impredicative.com/ur/users.html

It includes:

- BazQux Reader, commercial RSS feed reader
- Bitcoin Merge Mining Pool
- Ecosrv, a build server for firmware on network hardware
- Extensibl
- Oilprice